# Angular 6 Interceptor executing hundreds of times

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

In my Angular 6 application I have set up an interceptor because I need to reroute API calls that are going to another domain.

Part of this is building a new URI.

***Here is the Interceptor code.***

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpClient } 
from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";


@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {



    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("headerName", 
   "headerValue")});
    if(authReq.url.search('MS/')!=1){

        var url = 'api/RequestHandler/?uri=' + authReq.urlWithParams;
        this.http.get(url).subscribe(
            success =>{
            console.log("Succefully completed");
            }
        )

        console.log("Sending request with new header now ...");

        //send the newly created request
        return next.handle(authReq)
        .catch((error, caught) => {
        //intercept the respons error and displace it to the console
        console.log("Error Occurred");
        console.log(error);
        //return the error to the method that called it
        return Observable.throw(error);
        }) as any;
      }
    }
}
```

What I am seeing is the Interceptor code executed hundreds of times and each time the URI concatenation happens so I have hundreds of requests that look like this.

```
http://localhost/mywebapplication/api/RequestHandler/? 
uri=api/RequestHandler/?uri=api/RequestHandler/? 
uri=MS/MappingServicesWebAPIIntegrated/api/myApicontroller? 
Year=2018
```

with each successive call adding an extra "? 
uri=api/RequestHandler/"

and only 1 call that is correct "http://localhost/mywebapplication/api/RequestHandler/? 
    uri=MS/MappingServicesWebAPIIntegrated/api/myApicontroller? 
    Year=2018"

How do I stop the repeating calls the interceptor is picking up and constructing incorrect urls for?

Comment: Well, you're making a Http request in the interceptor, what did you expect to happen? Every time you intercept a request you send another one, which will be intercepted, ad infinum.

Comment: Okay...so I make the call outside of the interceptor, how do I either return the new URL or edit authReq.urlWithParams? to have it returned by next.handle?

Comment: Just change url somewhere. Like `authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("headerName", 
   "headerValue"), url: newUrl })` and then `return next.handle(authReq)`. And do not send another request.